# How to check whether an array of object is present in another array of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array like this

```
const arr1 = [{code: 'a', name: 'x'}];
const arr2 = [{code: 'a', name: 'x'}, {code: 'b', name: 'y'}];
```

Here I want to check the code vale in first array object is present in the second array's code value.

For this I tried like this  but it returned false

```
arr1.every(item => arr2.includes(item))
```

How can I check the code value in first array object is present in the second array object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const arr1 = [{code: 'a', name: 'x'}];
const arr2 = [{code: 'a', name: 'x'}, {code: 'b', name: 'y'}];

const codeValues = new Set(arr2.map(({code}) => code));

const isPresent = arr1.some(item => codeValues.has(item.code));
console.log(isPresent);
```